# Adding Debian 9 (Stretch) Backports to my sources.list

Tags: shell, security, debian

I am trying to secure a website by using Certbot, the issue I'm having is regarding the "stretch-backports"
This is the line of code certbot asks of me, however I get an error saying "stretch-backports" isn't part of the available sources.

```
$ sudo apt-get install certbot -t stretch-backports
```

So I tried adding the backports with this line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

But "deb" was not recognized. So I installed gdebi which is similar:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

With that installed, I tried the previous line again with a slight modification:

```
gdebi http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

And now it says "gdebi error, file not found: http://http.debian.net/debian"

So my question is twofold, if I didn't mess up in the previous steps, does someone have and functional address for the stretch-backports and is gdebi a good substitue for deb?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [official backports documentation](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)

> For jessie add this line
>
> ```
> deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
> ```
>
> to your `sources.list` (or add a new file with the ".list" extension to
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) You can also find a list of other mirrors at
>   https://www.debian.org/mirror/list
>
> For stretch add this line
>
> ```
> deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
> ```
>
> to your `sources.list` (or add a new file with the ".list" extension to
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) You can also find a list of other mirrors at
>   https://www.debian.org/mirror/list

Now these instructions seem pretty clear (rather than "pretty vague"), that you should edit a file, rather than run a `deb` command.

(Probably the "your `sources.list` " could be changed to "your `/etc/apt/sources.list`")

Comment: Thanks for the input! But we'll have to agree to disagree, I saw that documentation and for something official, I did not find it clear and I stand by that! I will admit that my answer isn't much better, but thanks to your intervention, it can be!

Answer (score 1):

You can also append the key to sources.list via echo.

```
sudo echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

My full install script is (all run as root or sudo)

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install certbot python-certbot-apache -t stretch-backports
```

Comment: For the pipeline version, the "sudo" needs to be on the "tee -a" call, rather than the "echo"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out how this works and wanted to answer because I felt that the documentation I found was pretty vague so this is how you add Debian 9 stretch-backports to your sources.list:

- Manually, and with admin rights, navigate to /etc/apt/sources.list then create your stretch-backport.list file then enter it with nano, in my case I added this whole line:

  ```
  deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
  ```

to this

```
 sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
```

And it was that simple, I could then use the following line without any errors:

```
sudo apt-get install certbot -t stretch-backports
```

There it is! Hope I was clear.